# double free or corruption (top) in IF section of function

Tags: c, malloc, free

I've written the follow function:

```
/*!
 * @brief Checks if a string contains a certain keyword
 * @param char *chkstring - String to search in
 * @param char *keyword - String to search for
 * @return int - 1 if found, 0 if not found
*/

int check_string(char *chkstring, char *keyword)
{
    char *buffer;
    char *buffer2;
    buffer = malloc(256);
    buffer2 = malloc(256);
    strcpy(buffer2,chkstring);

    if((buffer = strstr(buffer2,keyword)) != NULL)      // Check for first appearance of keyword in chkstring
    {
        //free(buffer);   // <- Problem sits here                                   
        //free(buffer2);  //    and/or here 
        return 1;                                       // if something is found, return 1
    }
    else
    {
        free(buffer);                                   // else return 0   
        free(buffer2);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If I run it with the problematic part uncommented I get an

> double free or corruption (top)

error. Why is this? Shouldn't the memory be freed in the part the function returns? Or did I messed up the if parameter and both instructions are used - which I wouldn't hope, because the code works like intended otherwise.

Thanks for your help to understand this matter!

Comment: After `buffer = strstr(buffer2,keyword)` you can no longer `free(buffer)`. Can only `free` the value `malloc` gave you.

Comment: As a bonus, you also leaked the memory from `buffer = malloc(256);` as soon as you did `buffer = strstr(buffer2,keyword))`. Looking at this code, *none* of it seems warranted. You're effectively wrapping `strstr` with a bunch of unnecessary memory management that isn't needed. *All* of this should be replaceable with simply, `return strstr(chkstring, keyword) != NULL;`

Answer (score 3):

Check [strstr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)'s return value.

> Return Value

A pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of characters specified in `str2`, or a `null` pointer if the sequence is not present in `str1`

This means that if `str2` is found in `str1` than it will return the address of the that location.

And when you `free(buffer)` you are actually freeing `str1` instead of the memory allocated earlier.

Also you don't need `buffer = malloc(256);`

**EDIT**: As pointed out by others, you dont need any buffers

```
int check_string(char *chkstring, char *keyword)
{
    //No need for buffers. Simply check in original string and return accordingly

    if(strstr(chkstring,keyword) != NULL)      // Check for first appearance of keyword in chkstring
    {
        return 1;                                       // if something is found, return 1
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Similar thing can be achieved by just 1 line

```
return (strstr(chkstring,keyword) != NULL)
//But then why do you need function if you only want if string exists or not.
```

Comment: Per the comment by @WhozCraig, you can reduce the contents of `check_string` to a single return statement including the inequality. (though with the `if` included, it may be more readable for those new to C)